# PHP Regex for nested patterns

Tags: php, regex

I have the following PHP string:

```
$str = "a b [[c], [d] then [e]] followed by [f] then [g]";
```

I'm trying to write 2 expressions in PHP; one to extract the [c], [d], [e] (including the square brackets) and a second regex to extract the [f] and [g] (including brackets).

Bonus points for anyone who can do it with whitespace added before or after a square bracket.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Comment: What's your expected output if the input is `[fs[sc][sc[gf]]]` ?

Comment: Any attempts so far? If it's always just two levels of brackets then it doesn't even require a nested pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this simple and readable regex (for two levels only and balanced brackets):

```
(?|(?<=\[)[^\[\]]*(?<nested>\[[^\[\]]+\])[^\[\]]*|(?<=(?!\A)\G)(\[[^\[\]]*\])[^\[\]]*(?=(?:[^\[\]]*\[[^\[\]]+\])*\])|(?<=(?!\A)\G)[^\[\]]*(\[[^\[\]+]\])[^\[\]]*(?=\]))|(?<simple>\[[^\[\]]+\])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iK0nL2/2)

I'm pretty sure, that there is (probably better) way to do that without regex, but this is how I would do that with regex. Probably there is also better way to do that with regex :D

About whitspaces before and after brackets, I don't know what you mean: inside or outside brackets? add whitspaces, or match whitspaces if its occour before or after bracket?